# R shiny renderTable change cell colors

Tags: javascript, css, r, html-table, shiny

I have a table and want to color every cell depending on the value (0-100) in X(=6) different shades of blue. The table is shown in a TabPanel.

Currently I am using shinyjs to call a javascript function which selects my table and add CSS styling to the `<td>` tags, depending on the value range.

The Problem is, that on the first loading of the table (click on TabPanel), no color is shown, only after reloading again.

So I am either looking for a solution in R (without the need for extra Javascript), or a method to automatically reload a Table/TabPanel.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tableOutput("dataTable")
  ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$dataTable <- renderTable({
    data <- getDataFromSomeWhere();
    //Some operations on data
    data
    //I want to color every table cell, depening on value (f.e. 0-5 = white, 10-20 = light blue ...)
  }, rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**
In the end I stayed with the JavaScript solution, but used the shiny specific js events to get the desired effect:

```
$(document).on("shiny:value", function(e) {
  if (e.name == "myComponent") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myComponent').html(e.value);
    //color code etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tableHTML` to create a table and style it conditionally.

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)
```

Change the `ui` to use the output function from `tableHTML`:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tableHTML_output("dataTable")
))
```

Then use `render_tableHTML()` to render the table that is produced within.

You can create a plain HTML table using the function `tableHTML()`. You can then use `add_css_conditional_column()` to create conditionals (in this case `between`) to change the background colour (Note: you could use other css as well. I have used `#f6f6f6` instead of `white` in the example, since you would not see a difference in the output)

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  getDataFromSomeWhere <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  output$dataTable <- render_tableHTML({
    data <- getDataFromSomeWhere();
    # //Some operations on data
    data %>% 
      tableHTML(rownames = TRUE) %>% 
      add_css_conditional_column(conditional = 'between',
                                 between = c(0, 5),
                                 css = list(c('background-color'),
                                            c('#f6f6f6')),
                                 columns = 1:ncol(data)) %>% 
      add_css_conditional_column(conditional = 'between',
                                 between = c(10, 20),
                                 css = list(c('background-color'),
                                            c('lightblue')),
                                 columns = 1:ncol(data))

  })

})
```

The final result is:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: shiny_app_output]

You can find more details on how to use `tableHTML` in the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will look into it. Since I have a lot of tables (all with shiny tableOutput/renderTable), I would prefer not to add another style/library dependency.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution in my opinion is to use the `DT` library functionality.
The table is more aesthetically pleasing and also keeps the scrollable table functionality. Both are immediately lacking in `tableHTML`.

Server contains the `renderDataTable` function where the user can conditionally format the table:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$beautifulTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    # display top 5 rows at a time
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
    
    # example dataframe
    df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))
    
    # set conditions and return the beautiful table
    return(datatable(df) %>% formatStyle('V6', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))))
      
  })
}
```

UI simply calls `dataTableOutput`:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # display the beautiful table
  dataTableOutput("beautifulTable")
))
```

Display result with:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And you will get:
[image]
More examples here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Comment: There could be a problem on my device but nothing gets displayed on the Shiny app, there is no table