# R shiny renderTable - conditional formatting

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-formatting

Looking for some help adding conditional formatting to a `renderTable` in R Shiny. I'm using `renderTable` instead of `DT` package `renderDataTable` because I have a dataframe of over 400 columns. `DT` was choking on the rendering, but `renderTable` seems to work very quickly.

Here is an example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(DT)
  
  fruit <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana")
  num <- c(54, 25, 51, 32)
  Oct2020 <- c(10, 15, 20, 25)
  Nov2020 <- c(5, 7, 10, 15)
  Dec2020 <- c(7, 9, 12, 17)
  Jan2021 <- c(6, 9, 2, 0)
  Feb2021 <- c(15, 30, 12, 2)
  Mar2021 <- c(6, 7, 8, 10)
  
  data <- data.frame(fruit, num, Oct2020, Nov2020, Dec2020, Jan2021, Feb2021, Mar2021)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 1, numericInput("numFruit", "Number of Fruit", value = 10)),
      column(width = 1, div(style = "margin-top: 25px", actionButton("btnUpdate", "Update")))
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      div(style = 'height: 200px; width: 500px; overflow: scroll; font-size: 90%', align = "left", tableOutput("dt_Fruit"))  
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt_Fruit <- renderTable(data, striped = TRUE, hover = TRUE, bordered = TRUE)
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Depending on the value in `numFruit`, the **Update** button will shade the background of all the cells green where the value is >= `input$numFruit`.

Comment: Thinking this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798941/r-shiny-rendertable-change-cell-colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option for you using two for loops to look through the table and style the relevant cells with a green background in html

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(DT)
  
  fruit <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana")
  num <- c(54, 25, 51, 32)
  Oct2020 <- c(10, 15, 20, 25)
  Nov2020 <- c(5, 7, 10, 15)
  Dec2020 <- c(7, 9, 12, 17)
  Jan2021 <- c(6, 9, 2, 0)
  Feb2021 <- c(15, 30, 12, 2)
  Mar2021 <- c(6, 7, 8, 10)
  
  data <- data.frame(fruit, num, Oct2020, Nov2020, Dec2020, Jan2021, Feb2021, Mar2021)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 1, numericInput("numFruit", "Number of Fruit", value = 10)),
      column(width = 1, div(style = "margin-top: 25px", actionButton("btnUpdate", "Update")))
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      tableOutput("dt_Fruit")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    values <- reactiveValues(data = data, data2 = data)
    
    observeEvent(input$btnUpdate, {
      
      data2 <- values$data
      num_lim <- input$numFruit
      for (r in 1:nrow(data)){
        for (c in 3:ncol(data)){
          if(data[r,c] > num_lim){
            data2[r,c] <- paste0('<div style="background-color: green;"><span>', data[r,c], '</span></div>')
          }
        }
      }
      values$data2 <- data2
      
    })
    output$dt_Fruit <- renderTable({values$data2 }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: This works pretty good, but doesn't seem to reset. For example, If I use the number 5, it highlights everything > 5. But then when I input 10 and click Update, nothing changes.

Comment: Updated the answer to deal with this. I had tested it only with decreasing numbers which worked but not when the updated number was higher. I've changed the reactive value to now have 2 sets of data - one is kept as the original dataset ("data") and one is over written with the background colour ("data2") and plotted

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect but I'm still running into a strange issue in my actual application. I copied your example into a new app.r and ran it just to review it. Then I switched back to my app.r to incorporate it. It built and ran, but didn't highlight the values. I added a print(data) and ran it again. It ended up printing the dt_Fruit table from this example but was running in a separate app.r??? I killed the entire session, re-ran my app.r and get this error: <bytecode: 0x000001b4711bd800>
<environment: namespace:utils>. I think it's something to do with sanitize.text.function but not sure.

Comment: Ah sorry I have no idea why that happens! I've only ever used sanitize function in this case so I'm not sure how it affects the app overall

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, improving by my [old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684162/r-shiny-color-dataframe/22699039#22699039).

```
library(shiny)
library(xtable)

colortable <- function(htmltab, css){
  CSSclass <- gsub("^[\\s+]|\\s+$", "", gsub("\\{.+", "", css))
  CSSclassPaste <- gsub("^\\.", "", CSSclass)
  CSSclass2 <- paste0(" ", CSSclass)
  classes <- paste0("<td class='", CSSclassPaste, "'")
  tmp <- strsplit(gsub("</td>", "</td>\n", htmltab), "\n")[[1]] 
  for(i in 1:length(CSSclass)){
    locations <- grep(CSSclass[i], tmp)
    tmp[locations] <- gsub("<td", classes[i], tmp[locations])
    tmp[locations] <- gsub(CSSclass2[i], "", tmp[locations], fixed = TRUE)
  }
  htmltab <- paste0(tmp, collapse="\n")
  Encoding(htmltab) <- "UTF-8"
  HTML(htmltab)
}

yellowify <- function(tbl, threshold){
  indices <- which(tbl >= threshold, arr.ind = TRUE)
  tbl[indices] <- paste0(tbl[indices], " .bgyellow")
  tbl
}

HTMLtbl <- function(tbl, threshold){
  print(
    xtable(yellowify(tbl, threshold)), type ="html", 
    html.table.attributes = c("border=1 class='table-condensed table-bordered'"), 
    print.results = FALSE, comment = FALSE
  )
}

# Shiny app ####

css <- c(
  ".bgred {background-color: #FF0000;}",
  ".bgblue {background-color: #0000FF;}",
  ".bgyellow {background-color: #FFFF00;}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("threshold", "Threshold", min=0, max=5, value=2.5, step=0.1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("coloredTable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  tbl <- as.matrix(iris[1:6, 1:3])
  
  output[["coloredTable"]] <- renderUI({
    colortable(HTMLtbl(tbl, input[["threshold"]]), css)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a sliderInput, I'm using a numericInput and coming arcoss a couple of problems. I have a column that has letters and numbers (ex. A123456789). If I put 2000 into my numerical field, it's highlighting not only the column with letters and numbers, but also the columns with values <=1000 and >=2000 (everything in between stays white). It's very strange...